# Target Event Listening in flutter

Tags: flutter, events, dart, widget, target

I want to implement a delete functionality on an iterated list of text widgets, so that when I click on any text widget, that particular text widget I clicked on will delete. Is there any way I can listen to a target event in flutter, so as to know the one the user clicked on?

Answer (score 0):

wrap your text in an `InkWell` :

```
InkWell(
      child: Text('some text'),
      onTap: (){
        //handle press event
      },
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can use **GestureDetector** widget. You can find an example and more information [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you would do that.

```
//initialize outside build
List<String> letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'];

Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            ...letters
                .map(
                  (letter) => GestureDetector(
                    child: Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(color: Colors.amber)),
                      child: Text(
                        letter,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                    onTap: () {
                      int index =
                          letters.indexWhere((String alpha) => alpha == letter);
                      setState(() {
                        letters.removeAt(index);
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                )
                .toList()
          ],
        ),
```

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: did this help you?